# How to sort hierarchical data represented in a flat list?

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

I have a Python (version 2.7) list of objects that has an implied hierarchy. If one or more SubThings immediately follow a Thing, they belong with that Thing. I want to sort the Things by their value and when Things are moved for the sorting, I want their SubThings to move with them. All of these objects have values. Example input:

```
Thing valueA
SubThing foo
SubThing bar
Thing valueB
Thing valueC
SubThing baz
SubThing flerp
...
```

I have working code for this in Python 2.7 but it's brute-force and feels inelegant - about 40 lines of code. First I create an intermediate data structure that groups Things with their SubThings, then I sort by Things' values, then I flatten the resulting structure.

I have a feeling there is an elegant one or two (or three?)-liner for this. It even sounds like a classic opportunity for a Schwartzian Transform but I'm not making the "Pythonic" leap that easily groups SubThings with Things - maybe something with itertools.groupby()?

For clarity: SubThings never occur without a parent Thing. Things may not have SubThings.

I've simplified by leaving out the reality that the series of Things/SubThings can be preceded and followed by unrelated objects. It'd be awesome to see a solution that passes those through unsorted, i.e. in the position they were, but that's not as intellectually challenging to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use accumulate to propagate the original index of the parent "Thing" to all elements in its group.  Then tie the value of the parents to each group and then use a normal sort on these tuples to keep Subthings tied to their original parent while sorting both parents betwen each other and children under their parent.

Note that you will also need to keep track of which item is a parent so that parents keep appearing first within their group:

```
things = ["Thing valueB",
          "SubThing foo",
          "SubThing bar",
          "Thing valueC",
          "Thing valueA",
          "SubThing baz",
          "SubThing flerp"]


from itertools import accumulate

parents = accumulate((t.startswith("Thing")*i for i,t in enumerate(things)),max)
keys    = ((things[p],p,p<i,things[i]) for i,p in enumerate(parents))
sortedThings = [k[-1] for k in sorted(keys)]

for thing in sortedThings: print(thing)

Thing valueA
SubThing baz
SubThing flerp
Thing valueB
SubThing bar
SubThing foo
Thing valueC
```

*This is all iterators and generators. There is no intermediate data structure (except internally during the sort).  The whole thing could be written on a single (monstrous) line but I tried to keep it understandable.*

As you suspected this is indeed a Schwartzian Transform so you can play with the tuple used in `keys` (decorate step) to get different sorting schemes.

For example, if you only want to sort between the "Thing" groups but not the "SubThing" items within each group, replace `(things[p],p,p<i,things[i])` with `(things[p],p,i,things[i])` in the `keys` generator.

If you only want to sort the "SubThing" items within each group without moving groups around, change it to `(p,p<i,things[i])`

**[EDIT]**  I just noticed that you are using Python 2.7 which I believe doesn't have the accumulate function in itertools.  If that is the case, you could write your own:

```
def accumulate(iterable,func):
    for i,value in enumerate(iterable):
        result = func(result,value) if i else value
        yield result
```

*I never used Python 2.7 so there may be some other differences that I am not aware of*

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate all your effort with improvements and edits. I have this working in my environment with one exception. I need to add a key function to sort Things. I need them to be sorted by lower() on their values. Thoughts on how to incorporate that? I wasn't planning to sort SubThings at the same time but since you built in that ability to the tuple keys, I need those also sorted by lower() but on a *different* attribute they have. Possible? Maybe getting too complex?

Comment: It shouldn't be too complicated as long as you can get the sorting key from the index of the "Thing".  For example, sorting by lower() can be achieved by using `(things[p],p,p<i,things[i].lower())` as the tuple.  If you need some other attribute related to things[i], you could define a function (e.g. getThingKey) to get it, and use it in the tuple: `(things[p],p,p<i,getThingKey(i),things[i])`.  This would only be one more level of indirection.